# Cannot process the data send by FormData in a PHP server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using FormData to send the content of a form but it seems I can't get my script running well. It send something to the server (PHP), but on the server nothing is received and it returns an empty array.
Note: I am not using jQuery

I have a form:

```
<form id="main_form" name="main_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input class="submit" value="Click Here!" name="submit" type="submit"><br>
</form>
```

I sent it with Javascript XMLHttpRequest Object:

```
Ajax.send(new FormData(document.getElementById("main_form")));
```

I put here the FireBug Info:

Params:

```
-----------------------------19926109411601--
```

Response:

```
// using the following
print_r($_REQUEST);
print_r(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// resposne
Array
(
)
-----------------------------139502076225657--
```

Request Headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Response Headers:

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

I also have tried another header than `json`, but to no avail:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

How should I handle this?

Answer (score -1):

I test with this and it works.

```
    <form id="main_form" name="main_form" action="test2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="text" name="test1"><br>
<input type="text" name="test2"><br>
<input type="text" name="test3"><br>
<input class="submit" value="Click Here!" name="submit" type="submit"><br>
</form>
```

The result like this:
Array ( [test1] => asd [test2] => a [test3] => asd [submit] => Click Here! )

Best Regards

Regan